# Faster to reuse a variable defined in a common scope or redefine it in each inner scope?

Tags: c++, scope, redefine

C++ specifically, if it matters, but I imagine the answer lies in assembly code somehow.

If we have multiple blocks in a common scope (say, a function) which each use a variable of the same type, is it faster to define the variable in the common scope and reinitialise it in each block, or redefine and initialise it in each of the blocks (or is there no fundamental difference)?

Example:

```
int i;

{//block 1
    i = SomeFunction();
    ...
}

{//block 2
    i = SomeOtherFunction();
    ...
}
```

versus

```
{//block 1
    int i = SomeFunction();
    ...
}

{//block 2
    int i = SomeOtherFunction();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If `i` is a POD type (like the `int` shown in your example), there will almost certainly be no difference at all.

If `i` is of some type that has a nontrivial constructor or an assignment operator that does something exciting, then there might be a huge difference and you'd have to compare what the appropriate constructors and assignment operators do.  If both blocks are entered, then you'll need to consider the destructor as well.

In general, you shouldn't worry about it.  Take the cleaner approach and declare the variable in the most restricted scope possible, as close to its first use as possible, and only refactor it out if your profiler tells you it is a performance problem spot.

Comment: It depends which block are entered, yes.  If both blocks are entered, you'd get an extra object destruction if you declare the variable as local as possible.  If no blocks are entered, obviously you'd get no destructions (and no creations!)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess most compilers produce the same code for both cases and an `int`, but I personally prefer the second option since `i` is in the smallest possible scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same if it's not a struct/class (though the register allocation is more obviously unconstrained for the intra-block usage which may help the optimiser, but any optimiser that needs that level of help ought to be put into a nursing home).

For classes, it depends on the relative performance of the constructor/destructor and operator=().  Therefore, there's no single, correct answer.  Still, creating the variables inside a more localised scope is better programming practice in general, and this concern would usually dominate.

Comment: In that case I'll err on the side of good programming practice rather than trying to eke out tiny optimisations, unless the optimisations turn out in specific cases not to be so tiny.